# Website "unsafe" on Chrome and other browsers

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, fonts, ssl, https

I recently switches to HTTPS with a free certificate from WoSign (https://buy.wosign.com/free/ definitely recommend it because it provides free SSL for up to 3 year and free renewal and multiple domains on one certificate all FREE) and I've been encountering some problems because of it.

All the browsers keep saying that my page has some unsafe content/script, which is totally NOT true. When I agree to view the "unsafe" scripts my fonts just load. When it's "safe" my fonts are just disabled...

Any way I can fix this problem?

[EDIT]

Here is an as you can see I have HTTPS ***with*** green lock. When I load the "unsafe" scripts my fonts just load.

[image]
<sup>(Click for larger view)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though you're still loading your scripts over http links, not https. Which is in fact unsafe, and the browser is correct to warn you. The fix is to make sure that all resources on the page are loaded over https.

Comment: I had this problem and i resolved it. Before I solved it I was able to go to HTTPS but with a yellow thing next to the SSL lock, but now it is totally green. In my .html file, I only have HTTPS link, no HTTP! So that's not the problem

Comment: OK, can you edit your question to include some screenshots of the browser warnings.

Comment: I added a image

Comment: [This support article](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1342714?hl=en) confirms that the error is there is insecure content on the page that is getting blocked.  Can you share the URL?

Comment: In Chrome, you can use the Developer Tools (F12) on the Network tab to see what content was blocked.  The connection will show as `(failed)`.

Comment: Well, problem fixed! Appearantly my fonts did connect to the internet, so i changed thet http to https. Problem solved. It was checking with Google so the change didn't wreak anything because Google uses https. Stupid me...